# How to serialize arrays?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Symptom: No serializer defined for type: System.Array

Since all C# arrays inherit from the Array class, I thought that this would be valid in ProtoBuf-net

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public Array SomeKindOfArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

[ProtoMember(2)]
public List<Array> SomeKindOfList = new List<Array>();
```

Should I register Array with the RuntimeTypeModel?

```
m.Add(typeof (Array), true);  // does not seem to help
```

Attempts:

```
new int[]{1,2,3,4} // works

(object)new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } // does not work

(Array)new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } // does not work
```

Another possible solution (can't find the SO url right now):

Have a list of a base type class items.

Wrap each type.  e.g.

```
class TheBase{}

class ArrayOfInt { public int[] value;}
```

The would then become one of converting to and from a list of wrappers.  Is there an easier way forward?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

protobuf-net really really wants to understand the data you are serializing; it isn't enough to have `Array`, as that can't map to any protobuf definition. Repeated data (conceptually, arrays) has a very terse and very specific representation in the protobuf specification, which **does not allow** extra room for saying, on an individual basis, "of [x]". In protobuf, the "of [x]" is expected to be already known and fixed *in advance*.

So:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int[] AnIntegerArray {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(2)]
public Customer[] ACustomerArray {get;set;}
```

will work fine. But `Array` will not work at all.

Depending on how important this is, there may be other options, for example (and you may want to tweak the names!):

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(DummyWrapper<int>)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(DummyWrapper<Customer>)]
public abstract class DummyWrapper {
    public abstract Type ElementType {get;}
}
[ProtoContract]
public class DummyWrapper<T> : DummyWrapper {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T[] TheData {get;set;}

    public override Type ElementType {get { return typeof(T); } }
}
```

with:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public DummyWrapper TheData {get;set;}
```

would work, I suspect (untested). With classes, there is a little extra room that protobuf-net can use to implement inheritance (which also, technically, isn't supported in the protobuf specification - this is a shim that protobuf-net squeezes in).

Comment: I like the names. I am going to find a way to incorporate them into my next project. They will be wrappers for dummies!

Comment: Any thoughts about a nice way to convert from friendlier .net to protobuf-net?  I'm thinking an extension method or two with a list of if(obj is int[]) statements might do it.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @sgtz can you re-phrase "convert from friendlier .net to protobuf-net"? I didn't understand your meaning there

Comment: ie. convert IEnumerable<Array> to List<DummyWrapper>

Comment: @sgtz well, that's tricky; normally I'd say "you can use a surrogate for that", but `Array` is going to hit a few other scenarios first, most specifically the inbuilt list handling. My recommendation would be: if you are trying to serialize your primary object model and it starts getting hard, then: don't - write a DTO model that looks similar-ish, but which is trivially serializable.

Comment: I've never actually come across what variants of good practice exist for DTOs.  Interesting.

Comment: @sgtz all I'm saying there is: rather than trying to twist any given serializer to suit your domain model; write a separate model *for the purpose of serialization* that side-steps the issue. Most serializers have expected scenarios and limitations - and it is not always correct to enforce those on your domain model.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try creating a new ISerializable object like this

```
[Serializable()]    
public class ArrayOfInt : ISerializable 
{
    public Array ....etc
```

and override the GetObjectData()  from the interface ISerializable

Comment: because the question explicitly mentions protobuf-net, which does not use `ISerializable` (but which can be used to ***implement*** `ISerializable`)