# protobuf Error when converting List<> to stream: No serializer for type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, stream, protobuf-net

I'm trying to do something that I think should be simple: Convert a `List<object>` into a `stream`.

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class MyObject
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyObject> myObjects = new();
            myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo1", Prop2 = "bar1", Prop3 = "something1" });
            myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo2", Prop2 = "bar2", Prop3 = "something2" });
            myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo3", Prop2 = "bar3", Prop3 = "something3" });

            using var stream = new MemoryStream();

            Serializer.Serialize(stream, myObjects); // Error is here

            byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=No serializer for type ConsoleApp1.MyObject is available for model (default)
> Source=protobuf-net.Core

Comment: Very old answer, but might be related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510589/how-to-serialize-arrays

Comment: @CoolBots, can you expound? I'm not aware of any overloads for MemoryStream() that take an array.

Comment: Ignore that comment, I went stupid for a second, lol. Check out Marc Gravell's answer in the link I posted above - old, but might be relevant to your case.

Comment: @CoolBots :-) Happens to all of us! Looking at your link now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add ProtoContract to your class like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
class MyObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/README.md

Comment: This is just a direct copy and paste from the link I posted in my comment. This answer adds no value; please remove it.

Comment: @CoolBots, it is not a direct copy paste. He customized it to the code in my OP. Not to mention that he posted it as an answer, and not a comment, which will be more helpful to future readers.

Comment: @Amit, thank you. While this is the correct answer, I ended up not using Protobuf. I didn't want to decorate my class properties with something that future developers will have no idea what it means. I just wanted to convert my list to a CSV string, so I wrote my own extension to do this.